# Getting current directory in Windows CE 5.0 using C# compact 2.0

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, compact-framework2.0

How do I get the current directory from which my EXE is running? I have tried the following two codes but they don't work.

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
```

Using above I get error "The name "Assembly" does not exist..."

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

also doesn't work.

**EDIT**
Ok I found another code that works but it is giving me directory "\Windows" but my program is running from an SD Card. I copied the program to "Program Files" folder on device but it again gave me directory "\Windows".

How do I get the current directory or more specifically how do I get SD Card/Flash Memory path?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem solved by using:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
```

Answer (score 4):

The following code works for me to get the directory where `myApp.exe` has been started from on a CE 5.0 system:

```
// i.e. "\hard disk2\my program\myApp.exe"
string assemblyLocation = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
// i.e. "\hard disk2\my program\"
string currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyLocation);
```

Comment: This code is perfect and worked for me to return my App directory. Thanks a bunch @FlyingFox.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a "current directory" on MS Windows CE, up to at least version 6.